# Improving the readability of a FParsec parser

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I have a hand-written CSS parser done in C# which is getting unmanageable and was trying to do it i FParsec to make it more mantainable. Here's a snippet that parses a css selector element made with regexes:

```cs
var tagRegex = @"(?<Tag>(?:[a-zA-Z][_\-0-9a-zA-Z]*|\*))";
var idRegex = @"(?:#(?<Id>[a-zA-Z][_\-0-9a-zA-Z]*))";
var classesRegex = @"(?<Classes>(?:\.[a-zA-Z][_\-0-9a-zA-Z]*)+)";
var pseudoClassRegex = @"(?::(?<PseudoClass>link|visited|hover|active|before|after|first-line|first-letter))";
var selectorRegex = new Regex("(?:(?:" + tagRegex + "?" + idRegex + ")|" +
                                 "(?:" + tagRegex + "?" + classesRegex + ")|" +
                                  tagRegex + ")" +
                               pseudoClassRegex + "?");

var m = selectorRegex.Match(str);

if (m.Length != str.Length) {
    cssParserTraceSwitch.WriteLine("Unrecognized selector: " + str);
    return null;
}

string tagName = m.Groups["Tag"].Value;

string pseudoClassString = m.Groups["PseudoClass"].Value;
CssPseudoClass pseudoClass;
if (pseudoClassString.IsEmpty()) {
    pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.None;
} else {
    switch (pseudoClassString.ToLower()) {
        case "link":
            pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.Link;
            break;
        case "visited":
            pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.Visited;
            break;
        case "hover":
            pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.Hover;
            break;
        case "active":
            pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.Active;
            break;
        case "before":
            pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.Before;
            break;
        case "after":
            pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.After;
            break;
        case "first-line":
            pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.FirstLine;
            break;
        case "first-letter":
            pseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.FirstLetter;
            break;
        default:
            cssParserTraceSwitch.WriteLine("Unrecognized selector: " + str);
            return null;
    }
}

string cssClassesString = m.Groups["Classes"].Value;
string[] cssClasses = cssClassesString.IsEmpty() ? EmptyArray<string>.Instance : cssClassesString.Substring(1).Split('.');
allCssClasses.AddRange(cssClasses);

return new CssSelectorElement(
    tagName.ToLower(),
    cssClasses,
    m.Groups["Id"].Value,
    pseudoClass);
```

My first attempt yielded this:

```ml
type CssPseudoClass =
    | None = 0
    | Link = 1
    | Visited = 2
    | Hover = 3
    | Active = 4
    | Before = 5
    | After = 6
    | FirstLine = 7
    | FirstLetter = 8

type CssSelectorElement = 
    { Tag : string
      Id : string
      Classes : string list    
      PseudoClass : CssPseudoClass } 
with
    static member Default = 
        { Tag = "";
          Id = "";
          Classes = [];
          PseudoClass = CssPseudoClass.None; }

open FParsec

let ws = spaces
let str = skipString
let strWithResult str result = skipString str >>. preturn result

let identifier =
    let isIdentifierFirstChar c = isLetter c || c = '-'
    let isIdentifierChar c = isLetter c || isDigit c || c = '_' || c = '-'    
    optional (str "-") >>. many1Satisfy2L isIdentifierFirstChar isIdentifierChar "identifier"

let stringFromOptional strOption =
    match strOption with
    | Some(str) -> str
    | None -> ""

let pseudoClassFromOptional pseudoClassOption =
    match pseudoClassOption with
    | Some(pseudoClassOption) -> pseudoClassOption
    | None -> CssPseudoClass.None

let parseCssSelectorElement =
    let tag = identifier <?> "tagName"
    let id = str "#" >>. identifier <?> "#id"
    let classes = many1 (str "." >>. identifier) <?> ".className"
    let parseCssPseudoClass =
        choiceL [ strWithResult "link" CssPseudoClass.Link;
                  strWithResult "visited" CssPseudoClass.Visited;
                  strWithResult "hover" CssPseudoClass.Hover;
                  strWithResult "active" CssPseudoClass.Active;
                  strWithResult "before" CssPseudoClass.Before;
                  strWithResult "after" CssPseudoClass.After;
                  strWithResult "first-line" CssPseudoClass.FirstLine;
                  strWithResult "first-letter" CssPseudoClass.FirstLetter]
                 "pseudo-class"    
    // (tag?id|tag?classes|tag)pseudoClass?
    pipe2 ((pipe2 (opt tag) 
                  id
                  (fun tag id -> 
                      { CssSelectorElement.Default with 
                          Tag = stringFromOptional tag;
                          Id = id })) |> attempt
           <|>
           (pipe2 (opt tag) 
                  classes
                  (fun tag classes -> 
                      { CssSelectorElement.Default with 
                          Tag = stringFromOptional tag;
                          Classes = classes })) |> attempt
           <|>
           (tag |>> (fun tag -> { CssSelectorElement.Default with Tag = tag })))
           (opt (str ":" >>. parseCssPseudoClass) |> attempt)
           (fun selectorElem pseudoClass -> { selectorElem with PseudoClass = pseudoClassFromOptional pseudoClass })
```

But I'm not really liking how it's shaping up. I was expecting to come up with something easier to understand, but the part parsing (tag?id|tag?classes|tag)pseudoClass? with a few pipe2's and attempt's is really bad.

Came someone with more experience in FParsec educate me on better ways to accomplish this?
I'm thinking on trying FSLex/Yacc or Boost.Spirit instead of FParsec is see if I can come up with nicer code with them

Comment: FParsec ships with an optimized version of your `strWithResult` parser: `stringReturn`, see http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/charparsers.html#members.stringReturn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mauricio said, if you find yourself repeating code in an FParsec parser, you can always factor out the common parts into a variable or custom combinator. This is one of the great advantages of combinator libraries.

However, in this case you could also simplify and optimize the parser by reorganizing the grammer a bit. You could, for example, replace the lower half of the `parseCssSelectorElement` parser with

```
let defSel = CssSelectorElement.Default

let pIdSelector = id |>> (fun str -> {defSel with Id = str})
let pClassesSelector = classes |>> (fun strs -> {defSel with Classes = strs})

let pSelectorMain = 
     choice [pIdSelector 
             pClassesSelector 
             pipe2 tag (pIdSelector <|> pClassesSelector <|>% defSel)
                   (fun tagStr sel -> {sel with Tag = tagStr})]

pipe2 pSelectorMain (opt (str ":" >>. parseCssPseudoClass))
      (fun sel optPseudo ->
           match optPseudo with
           | None -> sel
           | Some pseudo -> {sel with PseudoClass = pseudo})
```

By the way, if you want to parse a large number of string constants, it's more efficient to use a dictionary based parsers, like

```
let pCssPseudoClass : Parser<CssPseudoClass,unit> =
    let pseudoDict = dict ["link", CssPseudoClass.Link
                           "visited", CssPseudoClass.Visited
                           "hover", CssPseudoClass.Hover
                           "active", CssPseudoClass.Active
                           "before", CssPseudoClass.Before
                           "after", CssPseudoClass.After
                           "first-line", CssPseudoClass.FirstLine
                           "first-letter", CssPseudoClass.FirstLetter]        
    fun stream ->
        let reply = identifier stream            
        if reply.Status <> Ok then Reply(reply.Status, reply.Error)
        else 
            let mutable pseudo = CssPseudoClass.None
            if pseudoDict.TryGetValue(reply.Result, &pseudo) then Reply(pseudo)
            else // skip to beginning of invalid pseudo class                   
                stream.Skip(-reply.Result.Length)
                Reply(Error, messageError "unknown pseudo class")
```

Comment: That looks a little better, I guess I need to do a more thorough read of the reference, I hadn't found the <|>% operation yet. But I really wish there was a F# library more closer in concept to Boost.Spirit. Its syntax is really close to EBNF, and we don't need to worry about backtracking, as it has infinite lookahead, it's just a pitty it's in C++ :( On the other hand, FParsec error messages are really good

Comment: FParsec has "infinite lookahead" too, it just has a different default backtracking behaviour. If you prefer Spirit's behaviour, you could easily define operators (based on the existing ones) that mimic Spirit's ones. However, it would be a mistake to believe that you wouldn't have to think about the consequences of backtracking then. You can find a short rationale for FParsec's behaviour at the bottom of http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/parsing-alternatives.html and http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/parsing-sequences.html.

Answer (score 5):

You could extract some parts of that complex parser to variables, e.g.:

```
let tagid = 
    pipe2 (opt tag) 
      id
      (fun tag id -> 
          { CssSelectorElement.Default with 
              Tag = stringFromOptional tag
              Id = id })
```

You could also try using an [applicative interface](https://github.com/mausch/ApplicativeFParsec/blob/master/ApplicativeFParsec/Applicative.fs), personally I find it easier to use and think than pipe2:

```
let tagid =
    (fun tag id -> 
          { CssSelectorElement.Default with 
              Tag = stringFromOptional tag
              Id = id })
    <!> opt tag
    <*> id
```

Comment: Do you guys prefer the applicative interface just because of the order of the parameters, or is it something else? To me, pipe2 seems to be conceptually simpler (i.e. easier to explain) than the combination of <!> and <*>. Also, having the function parameter at the last position allows F# to infer the types of the function arguments. And when the function body is larger (in the source) than the parser arguments, which is often the case, having the function at the end also seems to help readability.

Comment: @Stephan: It's not about the order of parameters. I agree that pipe2 is better in terms of type inference, but I find it simpler to think in terms of applicative functors instead of ad-hoc combinators. This can also be applied to any number of arguments, e.g. f <!> p1 <*> p2 <*> p3... instead of having to use pipe3, pipe4, etc (i.e. flipped liftA3, etc). Also, I can easily (and intuitively, at least for me) ignore the results of certain parsers by using <* and *>